# displaying spreadsheet/grid on a browser after loading from Excel

Tags: html, solr, ag-grid

I need some help with picking the right tools for a project.

Would like to import a bunch of excel spreadsheets (preferably server side), join a bunch of columns, and display a single responsive, interactive grid/table/html5-spreadsheet on the browser to the end user. What are some of the better tools to go about this? Would Solr or Logagent fit the bill?

Is there a mechanism (in the tool for e.g.) so that what is being displayed to the end user on the browser via Data Tables is secure i.e. only data fields accessible / allowed for the user to view are only displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You question is too generic to provide a detailed answer.

Whenever I need to have Excel functionality in the browser I use SheetJS:

http://sheetjs.com/

Check out their demos:
http://sheetjs.com/demos/manifest.html

Hope this helps.